# What is this jetliner seen in the Falcon Crest TV series?

Tags: aircraft-identification, jet

[image]

I'm trying to identify this jetliner from the "Falcon Crest" TV series filmed in 1984  It's from episode # 068 <3.28> "Ashes to Ashes".  This is the only scene featuring the plane. There are other scenes with planes (stock footage) in this episode, but they feature different jetliners, which have been identified already.  Unfortunately, there's no shot of the cockpit and tail available.  Does anyone recognize this make and model, please?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is a Grumman Gulfstream II business jet, not an airliner.

The oval windows are very unique to both the Grumman Gulfstream I business turboprop, and Grumman Gulfstream II business jet. The small engines are Rolls Royce "Spey" engines meaning it is either a Grumman Gulfstream II or Gulfstream III. (later Gulfstream versions had the larger "Tay" engines) The lack of wing tip "winglets" means it is has to be a Grumman Gulfstream II.

Grumman Gulfstream II
[image]